# Wrong pixel values when loading PNG

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a png image which I want to read into a numpy array. I tried this using three different packages and they all give me erroneous and incorrect pixel values.

You can try it yourself with:

```
im = np.array([324, 476, 557]) 

cv2.imwrite("test.png", im.astype(uint16))

print(matplotlib.pyplot.imread("test.png")




print(cv2.imread('test.png'))

 [[2 1 1]



print(io.imread('test.png'))



[[1 1 2]
```

The pixels values should be:

```
 [[324 476 557]
```

Thus I am confused by what is going on here. Is it that the different package readers are not capable of reading 16bit images, because from what I read it should not be a problem for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using **OpenCV**, you need:

```
cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

to open 16-bit images.

---

Please provide a representative image if you want help with the others.

Comment: So is it that the image is being scaled down to 8bit? Because this range of values still seems low even for an 8bit image.

You can try it yourself with:
`   im = np.array([324, 476, 557]) `

    cv2.imwrite("test.png", im.astype(uint16))

    print(matplotlib.pyplot.imread("test.png")

</code>

Comment: Those values are low for a 16-bit image whose values can go to 65,535 but I haven't seen your image which may be dark at the edges.

Comment: I tried to put the reproducable example in the comment there but it wouldnt let me format it into code so I editted my original question.